# How to make a Python bot, that monitors messages in a Teams channel

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams

for a project I want to create a Python bot, that can read messages in a Teams channel. The Teams channel is in an organization and it's important, that there is only a read access for that one specific channel.

Maybe someone has an idea on how to solve this problem. Purpose is that the bot reads specific messages in a channel to make further actions.

I used the Microsoft Graph API and Azure. I tried it, but I haven't found a way to give the API a permission messageread for a specific Teams channel, without having it also globally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to give the API a permission message.read for a specific Teams channel. We have to give ChannelMessage.Read.Group permission to whole team to read the messages of channel.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you wish you can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: So the API has the permission to read the whole Teams instead of one Teams channel through ChannelMessage.Read.Group? It could also read the messages of the other channels?

Comment: Yes, using ChannelMessage.Read.Group permission you can read the messages from all channels in Teams.

Comment: Is there any other option to realize it? Maybe with outgoing webhooks